# UITableViewCell with multiple labels read as a whole, possible to separate?

Tags: ios, swift2, uiaccessibility

I've a cell that has different labels and images.
Now when accessibility is on the voice reads all the labels from left to bottom.

Is it somehow possible that the user can click on the different labels in the cell so that the voice over reads only that? Or do I need to create different cells?

I thought this was possible with

self.accessibilityElements = [view1, view2] but it doesn't do anything. It's still one cell that is read as a whole.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do `self.accessibilityElements = [view1, view2]`, you are changing the order , so the accessibility will read the view1 first and view 2 next.

You cannot select a label. You can select only a button. But If you want the voice-over to read all the elements in your table cell, then you should make all the elements in your table cell accesssible.

Try setting each element in your cell accessible. **The default value is set to NO**, hence the voice over skips all those elements.

For example:

```
cell.label1.isAccessibleElement= YES;
```

In this case, when you swipe from left to right, the focus will move to these individual elements in the table cell. Once all the elements are finished, then voice over will read the next cell , repeating the same process.

If this doesn't work out, then probably voice over is skipping the cell content view. Also try to make the

```
cell.contentView.isAccessibleElement=YES;
```